# How to pass binary data without Base64 conversion via SignalR in .NET framework 4.52

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wcf, signalr

I want to pass binary data without Base64 conversion via SignalR.  As converting to Base64 increase the size of the data and it will give extra load to system. The server is C# application and client is javascript.

Comment: if you are using java script which is sending using HTML than you must convert.  HTML has special character and will not allow binary,  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng it is more nuanced than that, though; SignalR can use things like web-sockets, and web-sockets : support binary; but javascript has ... kinda weak and awkward binary handling (although it can be done). Frankly, I'd probably say "stick with base-64" unless it is absolutely critical, though

Comment: @MarcGravell My understanding is that though .Net CORE SignalR supports binary, .Net Framework 4.x does not. Check this from David Fowler and Damien Bod - https://forums.asp.net/t/1979283.aspx?Send+and+Receive+binary+data+byteArray+in+SignalR

Comment: @FrankM fair enough; thanks for the link!

Comment: @MarcGravell Handling is most cases (not mime) means using base-64.  The link really doesn't address the OP issue with SIZE/SPEED.  If SIZE/SPEED is important opening a TCP connection and preceding data with a byte count would be an option.  The javascript can be the main communication link with a secondary TCP connection to send the binary data.